# I want to let users upload pics to the server but I`m having problem figuring out how to tell $_FILES what the file name should be?

Tags: php, mysql

Here  is my upload form that I tried to use :

```
 here $photo_id = $user_name.time() .


 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 <input type="file"  name"<?php echo md5($photo_id)?>" />
 <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
 </form>
```

Here is the part where I get stuck 
how do I name the file? I can`t use this way : 
    $_FILES[$_POST[md5($photo_id)]]['name'] 
as you can see I have the same proble with $_POST giving such a weird expression . 
I will also be updating mysql database with the filename .

Can anyone suggest a better way of naming files so that filesnames don`t clash . If I use a simple file name , it may coincode with some other file of same name and overwrite ?
tHANKX!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to give the file field's name an altering value.

Give it a constant value:

```
<input type="file"  name="photo" />
```

If you want to suggest a file name, use a separate hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?php echo md5($photo_id)?>">
```

However note that this could be manipulated by the user. You will probably be better off doing the `md5()` later on server side, before actually storing the file - if you want to use it at all, because

> Can anyone suggest a better way of naming files so that filesnames don`t clash . If I use a simple file name , it may coincode with some other file of same name and overwrite ?

there is a number of things you can do (there are excellent answers for this on SO already listing all the options and their advantages and disadvantages, but I can't find any of them right now!). One method that is *fairly* safe is combining the  value of the photo's name or the user's ID, and the current [`microtime()`](http://php.net/microtime). The danger of collisions this way is microscopic.

Comment: You can also use `file_exists()` to check if a file of the same name already exists.

Answer (score 0):

1'st look again at your HTML and correct errors

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="file"  name="photo" />
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

2'st after submit

```
<?php
     $uploadedFile = $_FILES['photo']['name']; // uploaded file - for db name and md5()
     $tmpName = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']; // uploaded tmp file
     // I assume you are not handling users for web form and you are storing them in a session, if you need additional input on form you can add some hidden values.
     $newFile = md5($uploadedFile.time().$_SESSION['user']);
     move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $uploads_dir/$newFile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use a simple name for the file input:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="file"  name"myFile" />
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

Then when your form is submitted, the uploaded file can be referenced using `$_FILES['myFile']`.

The file will be uploaded to temporary storage, and you then have to use a function such as `move_uploaded_file()` to move it to permanent storage.

Something like:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, 'uploads/' . $name); // Move file to /uploads folder
```

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php has some more info

**Update**

If you want to make sure that you're not overwriting files with the same name, use `file_exists()`.

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['myFile']['name']))
{
    // File already exists
}
```